# How do you run react-native app in production mode?

Tags: android, react-native

I thought you could do this with `react-native run-android --dev=false`, but doing this doesn't stop the developer menu from showing up when I shake the phone and the request url to the packager has `dev=true` in the url params.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There are two configurations `Release` and `Debug`. By default apps run in `debug` mode. To run in `Release` mode

```bash
npx react-native run-android --variant release #android
npx react-native run-ios --mode Release #ios
```

To find other available options

```
react-native run-ios -h
react-native run-android -h
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Any other solution?

Comment: FInd all available options from `react-native run-ios -h` for ios and `react-native run-android -h` for android

Comment: I can confirm this works as of Feb 2023.

Comment: From -h command: Specify your app's build variant. Deprecated! Use 'mode' instead. Edited answer

Comment: this command has been depricated . now use can use @WhGandalf answer

Answer (score 13):

After running the command:

```
react-native run-android -h
```

I found that the correct way to run it today in May 2023 is:

```
npx react-native run-android --variant release
```

Comment: Reading another answer here, I see the correct way to run it today, June 2023, is: `react-native run-android --mode release` because --variant has been deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

It's in the dev menu under the settings option.  The key is that you then have to reload the JS.  You can verify in your packager output that `dev=false`.

Comment: Is this settings menu only available on Android?

Comment: No, this menu is also available in iOS by pressing M key in the keyboard if you are using the emulator or by shaking the phone if you are in a real device.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
react-native run-android --mode release
```

--variant has been deprecated

Answer (score 4):

- You can also use the React Native CLI to generate and run a Release build (e.g. react-native run-android --variant=release).

Answer (score 3):

**Testing the release build of your app**

Before uploading the release build to the Play Store, make sure you test it thoroughly. First, uninstall any previous version of the app you already have installed. Install it on the device using the following command in the project root:

```
npx react-native run-android --mode=release
```

Note: This information is sourced from the official website.