# Publish React Native (Android) app to multiple clients

Tags: android, react-native, build, apk

I'm developing a React Native (only Android) app that I have to publish to different clients (without using the Play Store).

Every client have its own IIS server, thus the API's URLs used within the app must be built accordingly to the specific client IIS URL.

Right now I'm using a .env file where I specify the client IIS URL before creating the APK. This is a problem, because every time that I need to create a new APK, I have to change the .env file and build the APK and repeat this process to every client.

I'm trying to find a way to optimize this process and though in two solutions:

- Creating multiple .env files (one for each client) and corresponding build scripts in package.json which don't keeps me from having to create one APK per client.

or

- Find a way to read (in runtime) the config from a file that I ship with the APK and build only one APK that will work for every client.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `.env` files like `.env.client1`, `.env.client2` and more.

Then add them under `scripts` of `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "client1": "ENVFILE=.env.client1 react-native run-android --appIdSuffix=client1",
    "client2": "ENVFILE=.env.client2 react-native run-android --appIdSuffix=client2",
    "ios" : "react-native run-ios"
    ....
    ....
   }
```

To execute in local you can use `npm run client1` and likewise for others also. Same you can do for iOS as well.

Also you can specify variant - `Debug` or `Release`.

This reference will be useful I guess - [How do you run react-native app in production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406340/how-do-you-run-react-native-app-in-production-mode)

Comment: That's one of the solutions that I pointed out in the question. The problem with that approach is that I still have to build one APK per client.

Comment: So you want to build APK for each client using single command execution, is it so ?

Comment: You can use any CI/CD tool for this, where you'll have to configure the env only once and it will work - have a look at `appcenter` - https://appcenter.ms/

Comment: If possible, manage all clients with only one APK would be perfect, but if that's not an option, building tha APKs with only one command would be better than what I'm doing today

Comment: I think we can write shell script to achieve this task, only a guess.