# How to troubleshoot an app after its installed

Tags: react-native, expo

I just built and installed an android app using expo but upon launching it, the app crashes after the splash screen when it was working just fine when I using expo. I now wonder how am I to fix it when I can't even see where the problem lies.

Is there a way to find out what the problem is ? like some kind of `debug=true` option or anything else to figure out and fix the issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59091730

Comment: Not really because I'm using expo and the app is installed on my actual phone

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 3rd party plugin that does just that like [firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/usage) or [instabug](https://www.instabug.com/platforms/react-native), these are the 2 that I've used but I'm sure you can find a lot more.